# PHPOffice/PHPWord: Download Word documents directly when click download button

Tags: php, ajax, phpword

My code create Word template and instantly download when i run php file.

How to create a button that allow me to create and download word file when i click on it?

Thank you!

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$phpword = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$ran = time();
$section = $phpword->addSection();
$section->getStyle()
    ->setPaperSize('Letter')
    ->setLandscape()
;
$section->addText("Hello World!");

$file = 'test.docx';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
$phpword->save("php://output");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a curl request on a php file who create, save the word and return the path, then use js to make a auto-click on a hidden link who you have set the "href=" with the path and have the attribute "download=your_file_name".

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a tmp folder the same directory youhave the code and add this

objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('tmp/helloWorld.docx');
$file = 'tmp/helloWorld.docx';

if (file_exists($file)) {`enter code here`
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```